# Fetch timesheets from dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Does anyone know how to read list of timesheets from dynamics 365 crm. My objective is to read a the list of my timesheets and create an invoice from given period of time. for that i just need to know how to read timesheet data from dynamics 365 with some c# code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're going to have to provide some evidence that you've tried to do this yourself because you're not giving us a lot to work with. Is Timesheet a custom entity? Could you produce the invoice as a report?

Comment: @jasonscript I dont know much about dynamics 365 sdk but i tried few samples which show show to connect to crm and i could not find any references to timesheets. Honestly i dont even know if timesheets are set up as custom entities in there or not. i was hoping someone with experience in this are would be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: If am not wrong, timesheet is part of Project service automation (PSA).. Look for fetchxml/query expression samples for RetrieveMultiple & it will give you EntityCollection.

Comment: You will have to check the metadata to get the timesheet entity's logical name, which you can use in the sample code to start retrieving data. You can review the metadata in the UI via Settings > Customizations > Customize the System.

Comment: Timesheet data source?